# The meaning of this please $\in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ ( with small 10)?

Tags: mathematica

I need to know if it's the right meaning of this expression please :

$\in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ ( **Z** with  **10** in the bottom):

integer numbers / whole integer numbers  set (with ten ).

Can you please provide more details?

Comment: So hard for me to understand ... any explanation please ( like simple explanation)!!

Comment: It means to keep subtracting 10 from an integer (or adding 10 to a negative integer) until the result is between 0 and 9 (inclusive of 0 and 9). A more thorough explanation involving equivalence classes will be on the math stack.

Comment: thank you Dave, Monica